# Trying to make the kCIInputCenterKey for image filters based on touch location and The y coordinate is flipped

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I would appreciate some help on converting my X and Y touch coordinates to proper CIVectors. The code below is everything I'm using to have a "touch" be the kCIInputCenterKey coordinate for the bump distortion. It works somewhat but the Y coordinate is flipped when i touch the screen to apply the choose a center key for the filter. X is correct but if i touch on the top of the image the filter is applied on the opposite lower part of the image while retaining correct x axis location

```
var xCord:CGFloat = 0.0
var yCord:CGFloat = 0.0

func didTapImage(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
print(point)

xCord = point.x
yCord = point.y

print ("\(point) and x\(xCord) and \(yCord)")
}

@IBAction func filter(_ sender: Any) {

guard let image = self.imageView.image?.cgImage else { return }

let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3)
let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!)
let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: image)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortion")

filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter?.setValue((CIVector(x: xCord, y: yCord)), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
filter?.setValue(300.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
filter?.setValue(2.50, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

centerScrollViewContents()


if let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage{
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!)
}


}
```

The problem is the yCord is flipped for some reason coming from being a float to a Vector. When I try to correct this by using something like:

```
filter?.setValue((CIVector(x: xCord, y: -yCord)), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
```

or

```
filter?.setValue((CIVector(x: xCord, y: yCord * (-1))), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
```

It causes the entire image to jump up or down in the image view and the filter doesn't get applied to it anywhere. Not sure where to go from here since the value doesn't want to be flipped with simple math.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

to flip the y correctly all I had to do was:

```
filter?.setValue((CIVector(x: xCord, y: CGFloat(image.height) - yCord)), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
```

Comment: Please don't hesitate to mark you own answer as the correct one!